# How can I fix the structure of my methods in a linked list class in Java?

Tags: java, methods, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

I am working on a Linked List class where I want to manually create each method. My methods are showing the wrong output and I am not sure where I went wrong with my code. Could anyone look over it and give me some pointers?

The output (it should match my ArrayList output but it isn't):

Inserted Course 451 at index 4
Array List size: 6
Linked List size: 6
Array List data: 131 132 215 315 451 415
Linked List data: 131 132 215 315 451 451

Removed Course at index 3 from the Lists
Array List size: 5
Linked List size: 5
Array List data: 131 132 215 451 415
Linked List data: 131 132 215 315 451

Removed Course 415 from the Lists
Array List size: 4
Linked List size: 5
Array List data: 131 132 215 451
Linked List data: 131 132 215 315 451

Replaced Course 131 and Course 132 with Course 121 and Course 122 respectively
Array List data: 121 122 215 451
Linked List data: 121 122 215 315 451

Index of '451' in the Array List: 3
Index of '451' in the Linked List: 4

Is '215' present in the Array List? true
Is '215' present in the Linked List? true
Is '315' present in the Array List? false
Is '315' present in the Linked List? true

My Linked List class with methods:

`public class LinkedList{`

```
// linked list fields
private Node head;
private int size;

/**
 * Default constructor
 */
public LinkedList(){
    head = null;
    size = 0;
}


public Object get(int pos){
    // error for if the position is less than zero or greater 
    // than the size
    if (pos < 0 || (pos >= size)) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    Node temp = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++){
        // if the next node is null and return current data
        if (temp.next == null){
            return temp.data;
        } else {
            //System.out.println(temp.data);
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
    // gets the value of that stored data in that position
    return temp.data;
}


public void clear(){
    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
        head = null;
    }
    size = 0;
}

public boolean set(int pos, Object obj){
    if (pos < 0 || (pos >= size)){
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    Node temp = head;
    // loops through list until it gets to desired position
    for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++){
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    // the original data is being updated with the new
    // data(elem)
    temp.data = obj;
    // successfully updated the data
    return true;
}


public int indexOf(Object obj){
    for (int k = 0; k < size(); k++){
        Object elem = get(k);
        if (elem.equals(obj)){
            // found item; return its position
            return k;
        }
    }
    // item not found
    return -1;
}

public Object remove(int pos){
    if (pos < 0 || pos >= size){
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    // stores the element to be removed
    Node temp = head;
    // loops through list until it gets to desired position
    for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++){
        // if the next node is null and return current data
        if (temp.next == null){
            return temp.data;
        }
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    // subtracts size
    size--;

    return temp.data;
}

public boolean add(int pos, Object obj){
    if (pos < 0 || pos >= size) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    Node temp = head;
    // loops through list until it gets to desired position
    for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++){
        // if the next node is null and return current data
        if (temp.next == null){
            return false;
        }
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    temp.data = obj;
    size++;
    return true;
}
```

`

Comment: I'm looking at your `remove` method.  Although it reduces `size`, I can't see that it actually removes anything from the list.  You might have missed something out there.

Comment: I honestly think though that you'd do well to learn to use your debugger.  You can't really become a good programmer without doing that.